# Can't create class instance in Session Class

Tags: php, class, session

I am trying to record sessions in database. I created class and I am trying to call database class in its construct.
I get this error:

**Warning: Missing argument 1 for SafePDO::__construct(), called in...**

This is my database class:

```
Class SafePDO extends PDO {

    public static function exception_handler($exception) {
        // Output the exception details
        die('Uncaught exception: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }

    public function __construct($dsn, $username = '', $password = '', $driver_options = array()) {

        // Temporarily change the PHP exception handler while we...
        set_exception_handler(array(__CLASS__, 'exception_handler'));

        // ... create a PDO object
        parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, $driver_options);

        // Change the exception handler back to whatever it was before
        restore_exception_handler();
    }

}

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mynshost_tarrot;charset=utf8', 'mynshost_tarrot', 'PickTarrot2');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

And this is my Session class:

```
class Session {


    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        // Instantiate new Database object

        $this->db = new SafePDO;

// Set handler to overide SESSION
        session_set_save_handler(
                array($this, "_open"), array($this, "_close"), array($this, "_read"), array($this, "_write"), array($this, "_destroy"), array($this, "_gc")
        );

        // Start the session
        session_start();
    }

    /**
     * Open
     */
    public function _open() {
        // If successful
        if ($this->db) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Close
     */
    public function _close() {
        // Close the database
        if ($this->db->close()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Read
     */
    public function _read($id) {


        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :user_id");
            $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row_sess_data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            print "<h3>An Error occured!</h3>";
            print $ex->getMessage();
        }

        return $row_sess_data['data'];
    }

    /**
     * Write
     */
    public function _write($user_id, $data) {
        // Create time stamp
        $access = time();

        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (:user_id, :access, :data)");
            $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(':access', $access, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':data', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
//            $row_sess_data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            print "<h3>An Error occured!</h3>";
            print $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

// End of __write()

    /**
     * Destroy
     */
    public function _destroy($id) {

        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :user_id");
            $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            print "<h3>An Error occured!</h3>";
            print $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

// End of __destroy()

    /**
     * Garbage Collection
     */
    public function _gc($max) {
        // Calculate what is to be deemed old
        $old = time() - $max;

        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE * FROM sessions WHERE access < :old");
            $stmt->bindValue(':old', $old, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            print "<h3>An Error occured!</h3>";
            print $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // End of _gc()
}
```

Both classes are from real examples from Internet. The SavePDO is from PHP.net and the Session class is from here: http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/

I am trying it all day. Where is my mistake?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add your dsn in your Session class here:

```
$this->db = new SafePDO;
```

Since your construct doesn't have a default value for the dsn `public function __construct($dsn,`, it throw an error. Which is normal.

You should give this dsn to your Session class to be able to create a `SafePDO` isntance.

I don't know how you are using them, but you should run the first script and then, when you create your Session, doing something like that:

```
$session = new Session($db);
```

And then inside your Session class:

```
class Session
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {    
        $this->db = $db;
```

Comment: Thank you, guys! I think I have some progress, but not yet sure. Now I see this: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/mynshost/public_html/tarrot/db_sessions.inc.php on line 48

Fatal error: Call to undefined method SafePDO::close() in /home/mynshost/public_html/tarrot/db_sessions.inc.php on line 35

Answer (score 0):

You built object of `SafePDO` class without any argument:

```
$this->db = new SafePDO;
```

But `$dsn` argument is required

You must set it.
And you should set your database username.

See this example:

```
$this->db = new SafePDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example_db;', 'example_usr');
```